# generically typing a function that takes two arguments of the same type

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to recreate a prepend function, that will take an item and add it to the beginning of an array of like items, like so:

```
// a -> List a -> List a
function prepend(item, arr) {
    return [item].concat(arr)
}
```

How would I type this generically? I've tried

```
function prepend<I, I[]> (item: I, arr: I[]): I[] {
    return [item].concat(arr)
}
```

But it tells me I have a duplicate identifier. I don't think I want to do this:

```
function prepend<I, U> (item: I, arr: U): U { //...
```

since that seems to defeat the purpose.

I'm not sure if I should be doing something with another type (such as `IEnumerable`?) or if I'm missing something pretty basic.

Comment: `function prepend<I>(item: I, arr: I[]): I[] { return [item, ...arr]; }`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't have to type each argument between the `<>` (whatever that's called)?

Comment: No, you only have to put each *generic* type in the brackets. You only have one generic type, which you're then using in two arguments and the return value. See http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html.

Comment: Oh cool. Thanks, I'll try it out!